# awk/sed split a cluster file in to multiple files

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a cluster fasta file (called file) which looks like:

```
>1AB2
>1AB2 AA
NWWIEUNJRNIBGOWNGIOWGRBIGBRGRIOWGI
NCIDHFR8EHGBVPIWOBGIGRI
>1AB3 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>1SC4 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2CD5 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2AC6
>2AC6 AA
NFIGEURHGEIROHEGHTUTJGENLJBBEOWRIU
NFIROUHBOERVERUGBERUOVREOIBROEBVUE
NVHIRE
>2ONM AA
BUCIEHBUORBREOBWQVURVELLAJFLHIEBGR
NHEIBVEURIGBVNRIHEOEAJVSJDNHVUGBVR
NEBIBVVBRU
>2POD AA
BUFEWIBOEUWBWOREBRIUBGUERIGBVOSRIP
BUEIBVEO
>7KZL
>7KZL AA
BUIREBVAUREVBREOIRGPNJBFDVERUBVROR
>6HG3
>6GH3 AA
NBVUIREVOIAWRHRUGRTYUVDNJKDFHUGSEI
FHUIERBLUUIREB
>6GH4 AA
BDFUIGEVUERERHOBERIHBSDLKFJBNIERIH
NFHILRUGAURHG
```

the about file has 4 groups: `1AB2, 2AC6, 7KZL, and 6GH3`. the content during the first `>1AB2` and the first `>2AC6` belongs to the cluster `1AB2`. the content during the first `>2AC6` and the first `>7KZL` belongs to the cluster `2AC6`.

I want to separate the file into 4 files at the second `>XXXX`. each file should look like:

file_1

```
>1AB2 AA
NWWIEUNJRNIBGOWNGIOWGRBIGBRGRIOWGI
NCIDHFR8EHGBVPIWOBGIGRI
>1AB3 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>1SC4 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2CD5 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
```

file_2

```
>2AC6 AA
NFIGEURHGEIROHEGHTUTJGENLJBBEOWRIU
NFIROUHBOERVERUGBERUOVREOIBROEBVUE
NVHIRE
>2ONM AA
BUCIEHBUORBREOBWQVURVELLAJFLHIEBGR
NHEIBVEURIGBVNRIHEOEAJVSJDNHVUGBVR
NEBIBVVBRU
>2POD AA
BUFEWIBOEUWBWOREBRIUBGUERIGBVOSRIP
BUEIBVEO
```

file_3

```
>7KZL AA
BUIREBVAUREVBREOIRGPNJBFDVERUBVROR
```

file_4

```
>6GH3 AA
NBVUIREVOIAWRHRUGRTYUVDNJKDFHUGSEI
FHUIERBLUUIREB
>6GH4 AA
BDFUIGEVUERERHOBERIHBSDLKFJBNIERIH
NFHILRUGAURHG
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/^>/ && NF==1 {close(out); out="file_"++n; next} {print > out}' file
```

Based on your test input, the header, where you want to change the output file, is defined as: the row starting with `>` and having only one field. Using `next` we print nothing for this line, but set the output filename. Also a `close()` call ensures we will not end with too many files open as `awk` could raise an error for that.

---

Output:

````
$ head file_*
==> file_1 <==
>1AB2 AA
NWWIEUNJRNIBGOWNGIOWGRBIGBRGRIOWGI
NCIDHFR8EHGBVPIWOBGIGRI
>1AB3 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>1SC4 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2CD5 AA

==> file_2 <==
>2AC6 AA
NFIGEURHGEIROHEGHTUTJGENLJBBEOWRIU
NFIROUHBOERVERUGBERUOVREOIBROEBVUE
NVHIRE
>2ONM AA
BUCIEHBUORBREOBWQVURVELLAJFLHIEBGR
NHEIBVEURIGBVNRIHEOEAJVSJDNHVUGBVR
NEBIBVVBRU
>2POD AA
BUFEWIBOEUWBWOREBRIUBGUERIGBVOSRIP

==> file_3 <==
>7KZL AA
BUIREBVAUREVBREOIRGPNJBFDVERUBVROR

==> file_4 <==
>6GH3 AA
NBVUIREVOIAWRHRUGRTYUVDNJKDFHUGSEI
FHUIERBLUUIREB
>6GH4 AA
BDFUIGEVUERERHOBERIHBSDLKFJBNIERIH
NFHILRUGAURHG
thanasis@basis:~/Documents/development/temp> 
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csplit`:

```
csplit --prefix file_ --elide-empty-files --suppress-matched file '/^>....$/' '{*}'
```

It creates 4 files, named `file_00` to `_03` with the content that you need.

Answer (score 1):

using `awk+sed` combo:

```bsh
awk -v f="wfile_" '
/^>/ && length==5 {
  if (a++) print p, ",", NR-1, f a-1
  p=NR+1
}
END {print p, ",$" f a}' < file |
split -l 10
for f in x*; do
sed -nf "$f" file
done
```

---

We are using awk to determine the line number of the block initiators `/^>.{4}$/` and then construct the appropriate sed code