# awk split a file into multiple files with specific names in another index file

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a cluster fasta file (called file) which looks like:

```
>1AB2
>1AB2 AA
NWWIEUNJRNIBGOWNGIOWGRBIGBRGRIOWGI
NCIDHFR8EHGBVPIWOBGIGRI
>1AB3 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>1SC4 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2CD5 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2AC6
>2AC6 AA
NFIGEURHGEIROHEGHTUTJGENLJBBEOWRIU
NFIROUHBOERVERUGBERUOVREOIBROEBVUE
NVHIRE
>2ONM AA
BUCIEHBUORBREOBWQVURVELLAJFLHIEBGR
NHEIBVEURIGBVNRIHEOEAJVSJDNHVUGBVR
NEBIBVVBRU
>2POD AA
BUFEWIBOEUWBWOREBRIUBGUERIGBVOSRIP
BUEIBVEO
>7KZL
>7KZL AA
BUIREBVAUREVBREOIRGPNJBFDVERUBVROR
>6GH3
>6GH3 AA
NBVUIREVOIAWRHRUGRTYUVDNJKDFHUGSEI
FHUIERBLUUIREB
>6GH4 AA
BDFUIGEVUERERHOBERIHBSDLKFJBNIERIH
NFHILRUGAURHG
```

the file has 4 groups: `1AB2, 2AC6, 7KZL, and 6GH3`. the content during the first `>1AB2` and the first `>2AC6` belongs to the cluster `1AB2`. the content during the first `>2AC6` and the first `>7KZL` belongs to the cluster `2AC6`.

I want to separate the file into 4 files at the second `>XXXX` with specific names in this index file (ind.txt):

```
HG001 1AB2
HG010 2AC6
HG023 7KZL
HG004 6GH3
```

The result file should look like:

HG001.fa

```
>1AB2 AA
NWWIEUNJRNIBGOWNGIOWGRBIGBRGRIOWGI
NCIDHFR8EHGBVPIWOBGIGRI
>1AB3 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>1SC4 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2CD5 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
```

HG010.fa

```
>2AC6 AA
NFIGEURHGEIROHEGHTUTJGENLJBBEOWRIU
NFIROUHBOERVERUGBERUOVREOIBROEBVUE
NVHIRE
>2ONM AA
BUCIEHBUORBREOBWQVURVELLAJFLHIEBGR
NHEIBVEURIGBVNRIHEOEAJVSJDNHVUGBVR
NEBIBVVBRU
>2POD AA
BUFEWIBOEUWBWOREBRIUBGUERIGBVOSRIP
BUEIBVEO
```

HG023.fa

```
>7KZL AA
BUIREBVAUREVBREOIRGPNJBFDVERUBVROR
```

HG004.fa

```
>6GH3 AA
NBVUIREVOIAWRHRUGRTYUVDNJKDFHUGSEI
FHUIERBLUUIREB
>6GH4 AA
BDFUIGEVUERERHOBERIHBSDLKFJBNIERIH
NFHILRUGAURHG
```

I tried to use

```
awk '/^>/ && NF==1; NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1} (substr($1,2) in a) {close(out); out="cluster/"a[substr($1,2)]".fa"}  {print > out}' ind.txt file
```

but it didn't work, and I couldn't find the solution to the error.

Comment: Do you really have those empty sequences, headers with no sequence data? For example, the first line of your file is just `>1AB2` and the second line is `>1AB2 AA`, so there is no sequence associated with `1AB2`. The same goes for `>2AC6` and various others. Is that a mistake? If not, how should we handle those?

Comment: yes, that is a cluster file made by mmseqs. it means `1AB2, 1AB3, 1SC4,2CD5` belongs to the cluster 1AB2, and 1AB2 is the representative in 4 sequences.

Comment: Also a note regarding the try presented: You always have to put first the code for parsing the first file, when you parse two files with `awk`, and always use `next` at the end of the first file processing: `FNR==NR{...; next}`. This try is mixing the [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702775/awk-sed-split-a-cluster-file-in-to-multiple-files) with the first file parsing, leading to unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Ah, next means next file. Thanks

Comment: means next line of input! So for every line of the first file, `next` ensures that the rest of the code is not executed. When reading the second file `FNR != NR` so only the rest of the code is executed.

Comment: Ah, it means awk need to finish the first file and then to the next file

Comment: To anyone that is looking to parse the (oddly formatted) output of `mmseqs cluster`, new versions of MMseqs2 have the `unpackdb` module. https://github.com/soedinglab/MMseqs2/issues/406

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mkdir -p cluster &&
awk 'NR==FNR  {map[">"$2]="cluster/"$1".fa"; next}
     /^>/ && NF==1 {close(out); out=map[$0]; next} 
     out != "" {print > out}
' ind.txt file
```

The first condition-action (`NR==FNR`), is parsing the index file, to create the filenames and store them to an array, where the headers of the second file are the hashes.

When a header is found (`/^>/ && NF==1`), we define the output filename to use.

For any other line we print to the selected filename. Also I added a condition for not printing to a file `"cluster/.fa"` if ther is no mapping for this header.

Testing with sample inputs created these files:

```
$ head cluster/*.fa
==> cluster/HG001.fa <==
>1AB2 AA
NWWIEUNJRNIBGOWNGIOWGRBIGBRGRIOWGI
NCIDHFR8EHGBVPIWOBGIGRI
>1AB3 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>1SC4 AA
WNIOREHUEBRGOUERGHBERGIORBGREUGEGO
NWFWRUBGREOUEREOBRIOBNERIOBN
>2CD5 AA

==> cluster/HG004.fa <==
>6GH3 AA
NBVUIREVOIAWRHRUGRTYUVDNJKDFHUGSEI
FHUIERBLUUIREB
>6GH4 AA
BDFUIGEVUERERHOBERIHBSDLKFJBNIERIH
NFHILRUGAURHG

==> cluster/HG010.fa <==
>2AC6 AA
NFIGEURHGEIROHEGHTUTJGENLJBBEOWRIU
NFIROUHBOERVERUGBERUOVREOIBROEBVUE
NVHIRE
>2ONM AA
BUCIEHBUORBREOBWQVURVELLAJFLHIEBGR
NHEIBVEURIGBVNRIHEOEAJVSJDNHVUGBVR
NEBIBVVBRU
>2POD AA
BUFEWIBOEUWBWOREBRIUBGUERIGBVOSRIP

==> cluster/HG023.fa <==
>7KZL AA
BUIREBVAUREVBREOIRGPNJBFDVERUBVROR
```